# R- Replacing ifelse function for dplyr function

Tags: r

I am wondering how to replace this ifelse function, for a function from dplyr library.

```
df_w <- data.frame(
 n = sample(1:10),
 country = c("France", "Italy", "Albania", 
 "Australia","Austria","Belgica","Norway","Brazil", 
 "Ireland","Uruguay")
)

df_c <- data.frame(
value = c(1000,2000,3000),
country_name = c("France", "Italy", "Albania"))

df_w$country = as.character(df_w$country)
df_c$country_name = as.character(df_c$country_name)

df_w$n <- ifelse(df_c$country == df_w$country, df_c$value, 0)
#longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

I am obtaining an error "longer object ...", plus I remember to read in someplace that it is not a good idea to use ifelse, for the excesive number of validations.
I was checking other answers from stackoverflow, but for now I didn't find anything that fit with this problem.

Comment: `df_w$n <- ifelse(df_w$country %in% df_c$country, df_c$value, 0)`. For multiple comparisons it's `%in%` not `==`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas you rock!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also use Base R's `merge()` function. By including the `all = TRUE` parameter the empty rows are merged as `NA`.

```
df_3 <- merge(df_w, df_c, by.x = "country", by.y = "country_name", all = TRUE)
```

Then you can replace the missing values with zeros.

```
df_3[is.na(df_3)] <- 0

> df_3
 country  n value
1    Albania  7  3000
2  Australia  2     0
3    Austria 10     0
4    Belgica  6     0
5     Brazil  1     0
6     France  3  1000
7    Ireland  8     0
8      Italy  4  2000
9     Norway  9     0
10   Uruguay  5     0
```